# Flow Works in Debugger But Not in Sandbox

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a very simple flow to count up certain kinds of tasks. It is autolaunched on the Contact ID. If I run the debugger and put the Contact ID it works and the record is updated. But if I simply edit a record to trigger the auto launch then nothing happens.

Any thoughts on why this would be.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not a direct answer but you should look at what I posted to another flow related question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221439/help-me-get-my-flow-iteration-limit-under-control/221448?noredirect=1#comment336093_221448

Comment: That was also my flow question. And I used DLRS to solve most of my issues. But when I try to do one with Tasks I get errors from a Pardot Trigger.

Comment: Totally didn't realize it was also you :) But you should be able to use DLRS to handle this one too. I'm 100% certain the LREngine one could accomplish this. I love flows, but they are terrible for this sort of thing.

Comment: When I use DRLS I get the error below:   System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method: CustomPARDOT.ProspectAPIRequest(String, String, String, String, Boolean, Boolean)

Comment: I see, you could work around that using LREngine, I don't think there's anything you can do in DLRS.

Comment: You say you "auto launch" how do you do that? Flows do not usually automatically run on record edit (you have to do something else to fire them)

Comment: Runs from  Process Builder when a record is created or edited.

Comment: Can you update your question with information about your PB such as the criteria that is used to launch it

Comment: Added shots from PB